# Safari: Textarea is not autoscrolling upon selection

Tags: html, css

I have a textarea where the line-height is the same as the font size. I paste a large amount of text in the textarea so that I have a scroll bar. When I try to select and drag down, the auto scroll seems to work on Chrome and Firefox, but on Safari (11.1.2) on MacOS, the textarea does not auto scroll.

If I increase the line-height slightly, at that point the auto scroll does work correctly on Safari. I cannot increase the line height, so I am wondering if someone know of a CSS solution. I have a simple JSFiddle here with the HTML

```
<textarea style="display: block; font-size: 20px; line-height: 20px; height: 200px; width: 200px;">
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qdzow0rh/21/.

Simply paste a large amount of text into the text box and try to select the text by dragging the mouse up. Sample text to paste: 
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel quam urna. Curabitur odio ligula, ultrices eget mollis vitae, vestibulum vitae purus. Nulla semper aliquam risus eget luctus. Proin at suscipit lectus, sed viverra eros. Phasellus pretium quis tellus at aliquet. Sed suscipit tortor a tincidunt egestas. Sed quis ornare magna."

Comment: 11.1.2 works fine (cant see the problem)

Comment: anyway you can use rows="10" to remove element height and probably it will help.

Comment: Thank you. I am able to see it on two machines that I tried (Safari 11.1.2). Did you paste a large amount of text? This is just an example. We do need to have a height set in our real application.